# Question on Binet's equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, orbital-motion, newtonian-gravity

Is there a difference in [Binet's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet_equation) when the force acting on a body is attractive and repulsive?

I mean, if the force has a magnitude $F(r)$, is it Binet's equation always $$\frac{d^2u}{d\theta ^2}+u=-\frac{F(u^{-1})}{mh^2u^2}, u=r^{-1},$$ no matter if the force is attractive or impulsive?

Comment: You can simply change the mass sign to negative to describe repulsion.

Comment: so, the sign in formula changes when it's repulsive? When is it $-$ and when $+$ at the right side?

Comment: The one you have above is derived for gravity, which is attractive force.

Answer (score 1):

This formula actually holds for any central force, 
$$\vec F=F(r)\hat r,$$
not only for gravity. For instance, for an attractive (repulsive) inverse square force,
$$\vec F=\mp\frac{K}{r^2}\hat r,\quad K>0,$$
we have
$$\frac{d^2u}{d\theta ^2}+u=\mp\frac{K}{mh^2}.$$
As you can see they are different. The solutions for the repulsive case are unbounded while the attractive case can be either unbounded or bounded.